# TFS 2018 - remove HTTPS

Tags: http, tfs

I installed TFS 2018 and chose HTTPS only. Now I've changed my mind and want it to run on non-HTTPS. I changed the "Public URL" to http, removed the HTTPS bindings from IIS. But when I go to the TFS page in the browser, it's still forwarding to HTTPS. There are no redirects setup in IIS, which leads me to believe that the redirect is happening in TFS itself. Where I can I configure TFS to not operate under HTTPS?

I tried searching for an answer, but all roads lead to "how to configure TFS for HTTPS", nothing about removing it.

I've also tried different browsers, and cleared my cache to make sure the 301 wasn't being cached, which can happen.

Comment: Might I ask why are you trying to remove HTTPS?

Comment: Creating the Certificate Authority, etc got to be too much. I installed the Certificate Authority role, requested a cert but when I went to complete it, I got Access Denied. Since HTTPS isn't a requirement for my installation, I thought that it may be easier to remove it.

Comment: If possible reconfigure the application tier with HTTP.

Comment: What cache did you clear? Have you configured other feature, like Build service, with https? If you only configure application tier now, you could consider reconfigure it.

Comment: @Frank After you deleting the IIS bindings, did you change the *Public url* in TFS administration console?

Comment: @TingtingMo-MSFT Yes, I had changed that.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I cleared the browser cache for that domain.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and re-installing it and choosing the http only option. Everything works fine. But it would be nice to know what other differences there are besides the "IIS Binding" and the "Public url". I'm thinking that it's in the Configuration database somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean uninstall TFS?

Answer (score 5):

Once you remove the Site Bindings for https, you have to edit the **sslOnly** flag under Application Settings.  Change the public URL in Team Foundation Server Administration Console.  And you should be good to go.

[image]