# Can't use HTTP only within enclave

Tags: http, tfs

I have on-prem TFS within a small domain that we RDP into. Development machines are in this domain/enclave as well. Prior to the most recent TFS upgrade, we were able to connect Visual Studio to TFS and browse the TFS web UI using HTTP only within the enclave. We could also use HTTPS from outside the enclave (no http) to access the web UI. With the latest upgrade, I have mirrored the IIS authentication, SSL and binding configurations but now pointing a browser or Visual Studio at the HTTP only address always redirects to the HTTPS address and forces the SSL login. This is a problem for us because we use a large enterprise PKI infrastructure (access cards, non-local services, etc) that is very flaky: constantly dropping the Visual Studio connection to TFS and asking for PIN re-entry every 2 - 3 minutes. How can I stop the http address from re-directing to https all the time in our enclave? Is TFS doing this now? or IIS?

Comment: Did you just want to remove the HTTPS  use HTTP instead or want to keep both http and https work?

Comment: Keep both.  Use HTTPS from outside the domain and HTTP inside.  We had it configured that way before and it worked great.

Comment: Just found [this article](https://mattvsts.blogspot.com/2017/12/help-my-tfs-automatically-redirects.html) regarding the TFS public URL. It's concerning that the URL is used for anything besides what it says (primary(not only) URL and hyperlink provided in email notifications). Is it is also used to configure redirections now?  I changed it to the HTTP url and now pointing a browser to the http URL automatically redirects to https://hostname:80, think its trying to use public URL to figure out redirection.  Still forces https though for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Found [this article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/222231/unable-to-access-tfs-after-switching-from-https-to.html) describing the redirect behavior from the URL. Long story short-> In IIS, select the TFS under Sites, then Application Settings, setting name sslOnly was set to true.  Changed to false.  Now I can access the TFS portal from inside the enclave using http OR https and from outside using https only.  This means that VS can also connect to TFS via http only.

Answer (score 0):

Since TFS2017 server changed the Authentication from NTLM to KERBEROS by default. You could use the following command to use NTLM back:

```
TFSConfig Authentication /provider:NTLM
```

And please try to create a new DNS, then check the result again.

---

If you want to remove Https, you should  change the "Public URL" to http in TFS administration console, removed the HTTPS bindings from IIS.

If above is not work, try to uninstall and re-install the Application Tire and choose the http only option.

For  more details take a look at this similar question: [TFS 2018 - remove HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932164/tfs-2018-remove-https)

Comment: Will setting the Authentication provider using that CLI command cause https to stop working?  As mentioned above, I don't want to stop using https all together.  We had both working previously.  Outside of the domain, we could use client certificate mapping and https to access the TFS web interface.  Within the domain, we can just use HTTP to access the web UI and connect Visual Studio.  That was ideal, but now forcing all connections to be https is causing many undesirable issues.  And turning off https will cut our non-developer access to the TFS web UI--which we also don't want.

Comment: Just tried this--doesn't appear to have made an impact.  I'll restart the TFS and see if something changes.  I did look at the IIS logs and noticed that my request on port 80 receives a 302 response to redirect it to the 443 url.  Isn't that a setting when you set up TFS, to select a binding configuration where it's either https only or http and https with redirect?  Is there a way to kill the redirect?

Comment: @KJDietrich Sorry for the misunderstanding, 
you could also unconfigured TFS and configured it again without selecting Redirect HTTP requests to the Public URL option (checked by default).